# Difference between maximum resident set size as reported by /usr/bin/time vs. getrusage?

Tags: c, profiling

I ran the command `a.out` like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f"%M" ./a.out
```

`a.out` also uses the function `getrusage()` and prints:

```
  printf("%ld",ru.ru_maxrss);
```

where the first `ru` is the struct. When I run it, it gives me:

```
1228 
1632
```

What is the difference between maximum resident set size as reported by `/usr/bin/time %M` and `getrusage`?

Comment: Can you please include the source for `a.out`?

Answer (score -1):

According to the `getrusage()` man page:

```
long   ru_maxrss;        /* maximum resident set size */
```

While the man page for `/usr/bin/time` states the macro `%M` is as follows:

```
%M     Maximum resident set size of the process during its lifetime, in Kbytes.
```

Comment: My `getrusage()` call is the last call in the program right before the printing of `ru.ru_maxrss`

Comment: I don't see any difference b/w the 2, only when they're called.